# Storing tokens for custom token management

Tags: customsetting, custom-metadata, namedcredentials, refresh-token, accesstoken

I'm working with an API that does not follow typical OAuth standards and requires custom headers for passing the token. Typically I would use Named Credentials, but due to the atypical pattern it is not a good fit.

However, I'd still like to performantly manage the token so that each request is not making the same request.

There is technically two tokens that must be passed. It does not follow the Authorization Bearer pattern.

I'm trying to determine where to store the tokens.

I have evaluated:

- Custom Object
- Custom Setting
- Custom Metadata

Custom settings seem like the best fit as they are cached, but that also concerns me that if a token expires, I get a 401, by the time the I re-callout to get a new token will the next request be stuck on the old cached value.

Custom objects seem like they maintain atomicity, but at a high level does not seem like a great fit due to the ability to have multiple records.

Custom metadata does not seem like a good fit as it must be "deployed" to be updated, even if updated through Apex Metadata API, I think the dependency on deployment makes this a bad fit.

Has anyone else ran into a similar use case or experience with whether or not custom settings are a good fit for time sensitive requests and updates (ex: token management)

Comment: this is covered here - https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.secure_coding_guide.meta/secure_coding_guide/secure_coding_storing_sensitive_data.htm

Comment: Thanks, logically custom settings seem to be the best fit, but just found out that they don't support over 255 characters and these token surpass that.